# Regex to Remove Everything but Numbers, Letters and Spaces in R

Tags: r, regex

How can I remove these pesky backslashes in R? I've scoured the web and stackoverflow to try to find a way to get rid of backslashes...no luck.

I've tried a lot of different ways, but I think the only one that I can get working will be to remove every character that is not a number, letter or space using regular expressions and gsub(). Here is my string:

```
"_kMDItemOwnerUserID = 99kMDItemAlternateNames = ( \"(500) Days of Summer     (2009).m4v\")kMDItemAudioBitRate = 163kMDItemAudioChannelCount =     2kMDItemAudioEncodingApplication = \"HandBrake 0.9.4 2009112300\"kMDItemCodecs =     ( \"H.264\", AAC, \"QuickTime Text\")"
```

As you can see it is very messy, with backslashes and quotation marks all over the place. Ultimately, what I want to do is extract the movie name: '(500) Days of Summer (2009)'.

What is a regular expression that will match everything but numbers, letters and spaces?

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Comment: Where are you getting this string from? This appears to be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If the input string is in a standard format, use a proper parser instead of invalidating the format.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I could have given more context, but I just needed this specific answer. If I could get this answer, my larger project would work. To answer your question, the string comes from the shell command mdls, which extracts all metadata associated with a file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
gsub("[^[:alnum:] ]", "", x)
```

Try replacing the character class `[^[:alnum:] ]`, which will match any character which is *not* a letter, number, or space:

Full code:

```
x <- "_kMDItemOwnerUserID = 99kMDItemAlternateNames = ( \"(500) Days of Summer     (2009).m4v\")kMDItemAudioBitRate = 163kMDItemAudioChannelCount =     2kMDItemAudioEncodingApplication = \"HandBrake 0.9.4 2009112300\"kMDItemCodecs =     ( \"H.264\", AAC, \"QuickTime Text\")"

gsub("[^[:alnum:] ]", "", x)
[1] "kMDItemOwnerUserID  99kMDItemAlternateNames   500 Days of Summer     2009m4vkMDItemAudioBitRate  163kMDItemAudioChannelCount      2kMDItemAudioEncodingApplication  HandBrake 094 2009112300kMDItemCodecs       H264 AAC QuickTime Text"
```

Comment: Wonderful -- just what I was looking for! Thank you.